# Cross-origin problem loading video with pixi.js

Tags: pixi.js

I'm using pixi.js 4.8.8 and getting the cross-origin problem trying to load a webm video. 
Chrome says "Access to video at 'http://techslides.com/demos/sample-videos/small.webm' from origin 'http://localhost' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource." 
I did set videoElement.crossOrigin = 'anonymous' and I pass true as the cross-origin parameter to PIXI.Texture.fromVideo. What am I doing wrong? The webm plays fine if I just paste the URL into Chrome, so it should be accessible.
Here is the relevant code:

```
    // create a video element...
    const videoElement = document.createElement('video');

    videoElement.crossOrigin = 'anonymous';
    videoElement.setAttribute('preload', 'auto');
    videoElement.setAttribute('playsinline', '');
    videoElement.setAttribute('autoplay', '');

    const sourceElement = document.createElement('source');

    sourceElement.src = 'http://techslides.com/demos/sample-videos/small.webm';

    videoElement.appendChild(sourceElement);

    // next create a video texture; args = video, scale mode, cross-origin, autoplay
    const videoTexture = PIXI.Texture.fromVideo(videoElement, PIXI.settings.SCALE_MODE, true, false);

    // create a sprite to render
    const sprite = new PIXI.Sprite(videoTexture);
```

Comment: That remote URL is not responding with an `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` header - so you can not load this while specifying `crossOrigin = 'anonymous'`. And if you load it without, then you will probably not have access to the video data, to create any texture from it, it will most likely be considered tainted. So the only solution then would be that you go find yourself a video source that _is_ CORS-enabled; or you might have to set up a CORS proxy.

Comment: Thanks! This was just for testing, so I'll see if I can find a CORS-enabled source.